# QML QtQuick. Dynamically created component does not work with bindings and basic methods

Tags: qt, qml, components, dynamically-generated

Env: OS - win 10 x86, qtcreator 4.6.1, mingw 5.3, qt 5.11

Create rect1.qml file with Rectangle.

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {

    width: 40
    height: 40; 
    border.color: "blue"
    color: "green"; 
   width: childrenRect.width 
    height:   childrenRect.height 
   property int sub_border: 1 
   property color item_color: "green" 
   property bool view_bounding_box: false 
   property int sub_border: 1 

   onView_bounding_boxChanged: { 
       root.border.width = root.view_bounding_box ? sub_border : 0 
      console.log("BaseContainer", root.view_bounding_box, root.border.color) }
   }
```

In main.qml dynamically create component

```
Rectangle {
    id: root
    border.color: "blue"
    border.width: 0
    focus: true

    property int     edge_len:           20
    property bool    view_bounding_box:  false
    property var     active_object
    property var     deactivate_objects:[]
function loadComponent () {        
        var component = Qt.createComponent("rect1.qml");
        if (component .status === Component.Ready) {
            active_object = component.createObject(root, { 
            "view_bounding_box": root.view_bounding_box });
        }else if (component.status === Component.Error) {
            console.log("error creating component");
            console.log(component.errorString());
        }
    }
```

if I change bounding property root.view_bounding_box - in the generated instance(active_object), the signal handler will not be called.
If I call the "contains" method of active_object with args Qt.point(active_object.x, active_object.y), nothing happens, as if a stub is called

```
var point = Qt.point(active_object.x, active_object.y)
for (var i = 0;  i <  deactivate_objects.length; i++) {                
                if (deactivate_objects[i].contains(point)) {             // not worked       
                    deactivate_objects.push(active_object)
                    loadComponent ()
                    return
                }
            }
if (!root.contains(point)) {                                                     // worked
                deactivate_objects.push(active_object)
                loadComponent ()
            }
```

Border color in the active_objectis is "green" like rectangle color.

It's a bug or I something  don't understand in qml?

Comment: I am unsure, whether you create a binding here: `component.createObject(root, { 
            "view_bounding_box": root.view_bounding_box })` - I can't test it right now, but I guess to create bindings with JS, you need to call [Qt.binding(function() { return root.view_bounding_box })](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#binding-method)

Comment: You call `loadComponent (base_containers[getRandom(base_containers.length - 1)])` with an argument. Your function declaration does not take an argument? What is `Logic`? What do you have in  `deactivate_objects`? Have you verified that any of its content contains that point?

Comment: I have no idea, what you are trying to do, but have you tried to do it declarative/with QML instead of JS?

Comment: Yes, Qt.binding is worked, but in qt examples you dont find it. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-dynamicscene-content-itemcreation-js.html

Comment: You call loadComponent... I cut out a piece of code for convenience.

Comment: I have no idea, what you are trying to do, but have you tried to do it declarative/with QML instead of JS? -- Statically created objects(and with Repeat etc) work well. But in situations with a variable number of objects of different types, this does not work.

Comment: With a `Repeater`, a `Loader` as delegate and a proper model you can have a variable number of objects of different types, too. It also gives you the benefit, that the GC has no chance to kill your objects occasionally (*dtech can tell you something about the GC :D*), you can use bindings (even the optimized ones), and that you are more declarative.

Comment: The Repeater type creates all of its delegate items when the repeater is first created. This can be inefficient if there are a large number of delegate items and not all of the items are required to be visible at the same time. If this is the case, consider using other view types like ListView (which only creates delegate items when they are scrolled into view) or use the Dynamic Object Creation methods to create items as they are required. Loader - this object can create only one componnent at time. And my question is still  - Why dynamically created component does not work?

Comment: :D If a `ListView` suits your needs, sure! But often-times linear lists don't cut it, so a `Repeater` and a smart model will do a better job. To your question(s): I don't see them not working. As said: You don't create a binding, so don't expect a binding. And for the second question: have you verified that any of your random values fulfills your condition? More can not be verified, since your example is far from beeing complete.

Answer (score 0):

The "contains(point)" method does not work apparently because "invocable" and "virtual".
Automatic binding for dynamically created objects does not work. You must do manual binding for the selected properties.